# Search Blob storage files content using azure search

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I want to do a full text search on HTML files in the blob storage.I have created an azure search service, added data source to the service and created index and indexer through Azure portal.

I tested the Azure search service in the portal using Search explorer.It works fine.

But I wanted to display the search results in Console window using c# code instead of testing on search explorer.

Do I have to write a POJO class for DataSource even if data source for the service is created through Azure Portal

Followig is the code snippet

```
SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(searchServiceKey));

ISearchIndexClient indexClient = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(indexName);

DocumentSearchResult searchResults = indexClient.Documents.Search(searchText);
```

I want to convert search results object to readable text and display in Console window. I tried Base64Decode method but no expected result. Please help me through this issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, what *did* you get? HTML?

Comment: I am getting searchResults object

Comment: DocumentSearchResult .Results? Looking at it here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.documentsearchresult?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I would like to know how to extract the search result content from search result object

Answer (score 1):

The Document you receive will be JSON that contains each of the fields of the search document.

Your question is not clear as to whether you want to display the original HTML or the text extracted from the HTML document.

If you only care about the text (without HTML formatting), take a look at the *content* field. It will have the information that you need.  Make sure the *content* field is retrievable in your search index so you get it as part of the result.

If you want the document with actual HTML formatting, usually that is not part of the result document as that is not indexed. In these cases, usually people add the *metadata_storage_path* to the index make sure that it is retrievable. Then using that path you can just go and read the original file from blob storage.  If you used the *metadata_storage_path* field as the key of your index, and encoded it using base64, make sure to decode the path.